# cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse - error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I made a project in Android Studio with Google Cloud Platform Java sample project from github a year ago. It was working correctly by then but a month ago when I opened the project, I faced the following error:

```
error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
```

I have checked other solutions on SO,[Ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407069/an-enum-switch-case-label-must-be-the-unqualified-name-of-an-enumeration-constan), but on the StreamingRecognizeResponse class I saw the code is written as the solution suggests. Ex:

```
protected final Object dynamicMethod(
  com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.MethodToInvoke method,
  Object arg0, Object arg1) {
switch (method) {
  case NEW_MUTABLE_INSTANCE: {
    return new com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse();
  }
  case IS_INITIALIZED: {      //**clicking on first error takes to this line.** but it is as solution suggests.
    return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
  }
  case MAKE_IMMUTABLE: {
    results_.makeImmutable();
    return null;
  }
  case NEW_BUILDER: {
    return new Builder();
  }
  case VISIT: {...
 ...................
```

I can't compile my project anymore and I need to fix this error.
Any suggestion to solve this problem would help.

Comment: did you get any solution to this issue? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which Java sample you are referring to, but `com.google.protobuf` enumeration [`GeneratedMessageLite.MethodToInvoke`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite.MethodToInvoke.html) generally has these constants:

```
Object dynamicMethod(MethodToInvoke method, Object arg0, Object arg1) {
    switch (method) {
        case GET_DEFAULT_INSTANCE: {
            return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
        }
        case GET_PARSER: {
            break;
        }
        case IS_INITIALIZED: {
            break;
        }
        case MAKE_IMMUTABLE: {
            results_.makeImmutable();
            return null;
        }
        case MERGE_FROM: {
            break;
        }
        case NEW_BUILDER: {
            return new Builder();
        }
        case NEW_INSTANCE: {
            return new com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse();
        }
        case PARSE_PARTIAL_FROM: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no `NEW_MUTABLE_INSTANCE` and there is no `VISIT`. One can also list them:

```
for (GeneratedMessageLite.MethodToInvoke c : GeneratedMessageLite.MethodToInvoke.values()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Also see [`StreamingRecognizeResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse).

Comment: Although I left the project but I believe the issue raised from this project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech . Clicking on the error lines took me to a file that had codes mentioned.